# Assembly (x86): Number of '01' repetitions in binary code of HEX number

Tags: assembly, x86, binary, instructions

I'm new to Assembly and I have a task to determine a number of **01** repetitions in a binary code of a 16b hex number. For example:

Number AB34 is: 1**010 101**1 0**01**1 **01**00

As 01's are bolded above, they need to be counted and stored in RESULT in the code below. The trick is to **only use logical instructions** such as AND, NOT, OR, XOR, moving (SHL, SHR), rotating (ROR/RCR, ROL/RCL) and logical comparing.

Here is what I have:

```
name program

data segment
    BR dw 0AB34H ;
    RESULT db 0
data ends

code segment
    assume CS:code, DS:data
start:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ax, BR
    mov cx, 16
    mov bx, 0

lwhile:
    ; something with logical instructions
loop lwhile

    mov RESULT, bl

    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
code ends

end start
```

I'm assuming that inside the loop some work needs to be done, counted through some register like bx and then moved to RESULT.

I'm open to any suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: The interesting question is how to do this *efficiently* without restrictions on instruction choice.  For example, you can clear the lowest set bit with `x = (x-1)&x;`  (`lea ax, [si-1]` / `and si, ax`).  But I can't think of anything right away that's special for `01`.  Or for collapsing repeated runs of `1` to set up for a `popcnt`.  Possibly loop with [`blsr`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/BLSR.html) + `lzcnt` and check if the bit you cleared was the bit right after the previous one?  So your loop runs once per set bit, rather than 16/32/64 times.  But not just once per 01 match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should making ample use of the `and`, `cmp` and `shr` instructions. Look them up and try them out.

Overall, your code would have a structure like this:

1. Copy the `BR` value to a working register (*e.g.*, `bx`)
2. Check the lowest two bits for 01 and increment your counter if they are
3. Shift working register to the right by one bit
4. Go to 2 [do this 15 times, as there are 16 bits in `BR` and you're checking pairs of bits]

I'm leaving some details to you. Part of your code inside step 2 might look like this:

```
    mov  ax, bx        ; Current shifted value of BR
    and  ax, 03h       ; Mask out (zero) all but the lowest two bits
    cmp  ax, 1         ; Check if the lower two bits are 01
    jne  next_bits     ; Jump if nonzero (no, they are not 01)

    ; increment your counter here

next_bits:
    ...
```

`cmp` will check if the current pair of bits that have been shifted down to the lower order two bits are `01`. To check the next pair of bits, use the `shr` instruction. Your loop would continue shifting by one bit until you've exhausted all the bits in the working register.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still figuring out xor/and/not instructions and what they actually  do. I'll try it out.

Comment: @DušanJovanović those instructions are what they call "bitwise" instructions. They operate on *corresponding bits*. `not` is *unary* (has one operand) and simply inverts all of the bits (0 becomes 1, 1 becomes 0). `and` yields a result whose bits are individually the logical AND of the corresponding bits of the two operands (1 AND 1 yields 1, 0 AND anything is 0). Etc...

Comment: I figured it out, thank you very much!
mov ax, BR
    mov cx, 15
    mov bx, 0

while_loop:
    mov dx, ax
    and ax, 03h
    xor ax, 1
    jne next

    add bx,1

    next:
    mov ax, dx
    shr ax, 1
loop while_loop

    mov RESULT, bl

Comment: @DušanJovanović that's great. I'm glad you successfully worked through it.